# How to create a map activity in one activity on button click in other activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, button, dictionary

I am creating an android app for an University. I am trying to display a Location map in one activity by clicking a button in other activity. I have referred some links and worked, but I am getting error. Here is my code snippet and the Logcat. Please anybody help me in making this work.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
package="com.example.university"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.university.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.university.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00000000" android:required="true" />

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyDGPcb88FGrYilWxe41RbWog38pSgNfp5o" />

<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".About" android:label="@string/title_activity_about" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Chancellor"           android:label="@string/title_activity_chancellor" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Prochancellor"            android:label="@string/title_activity_prochancellor" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Programs"           android:label="@string/title_activity_programs" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Contact"           android:label="@string/title_activity_contact" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity"            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Admissions"             android:label="@string/title_activity_admissions" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Map" android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >
</activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

THIS .JAVA AND .XML FILES FOR BUTTON AND ONCLICK FUNCTION TO WORK

Contact.java

```
package com.example.university;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;



public class Contact extends ActionBarActivity {
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// Get the view from activity_contact.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);

// Locate the button in activity_contact.xml
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

// Capture button clicks
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


// Start NewActivity.class
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Contact.this,
                    Map.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
}
});
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contact, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

switch (item.getItemId()) {

case R.id.about:
Intent a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), About.class);
startActivity(a);
return true;    

case R.id.chancellor:
Intent b = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Chancellor.class);
startActivity(b);
return true;

case R.id.prochancellor:
Intent c = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Prochancellor.class);
startActivity(c);
return true;

case R.id.programs:
Intent d = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Programs.class);
startActivity(d);
return true; 

case R.id.admissions:
Intent e = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Admissions.class);
startActivity(e);
return true;

case R.id.contact:
Intent f = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Contact.class);
startActivity(f);
return true;

default:

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
}
```

activity_contact.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/tiny_grid"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.university.Contact" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/campus1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="100 Feet Ring Road, BSK III Stage, Bangalore-560085"
    android:textSize="11dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="+91 80 26721983"
    android:textSize="11dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="+91 80 26722108"
    android:textSize="11dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:autoLink="email"
    android:text="admissions@pes.edu"
    android:textSize="11dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:src="@drawable/campus2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
    android:text=" Hosur Road Campus (1 Km before Electronic City), Bangalore - 560 100"
    android:textSize="11dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:text="+91 80 66186610"
    android:textSize="11dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:text="+91 80 66186611"
    android:textSize="11dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
    android:autoLink="email"
    android:text="admissions@pes.edu"
    android:textSize="11dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:src="@drawable/campus3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
    android:text="National Highway 219, Kuppam, Andhra Pradesh - 517 425"
    android:textSize="11dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
    android:text="085 70 256736"
    android:textSize="11dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView10"
    android:autoLink="email"
    android:text="admissions@pes.edu"
    android:textSize="11dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:src="@drawable/campus4" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
    android:text="100 Feet Ring Road, BSK III Stage, Bangalore-560085"
    android:textSize="11dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
    android:text="+91 80 26721983"
    android:textSize="11dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView13"
    android:text="+91 80 26722108"
    android:textSize="11dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
    android:autoLink="email"
    android:text="admissions@pes.edu"
    android:textSize="11dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

THIS .JAVA NAD .XML FILES TO DISPLAY MAP

```
package com.example.university;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;


import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Map extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

    if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
             "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS", 
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }else{

          }
}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

      if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
         "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS", 
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       Log.v(">>>>>>>>>>>>>.", "successs");
      }else{

      }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
switch (item.getItemId()) {

case R.id.about:
Intent a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), About.class);
startActivity(a);
return true;    

case R.id.chancellor:
Intent b = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Chancellor.class);
startActivity(b);
return true;

case R.id.prochancellor:
Intent c = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Prochancellor.class);
startActivity(c);
return true;

case R.id.programs:
Intent d = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Programs.class);
startActivity(d);
return true; 

case R.id.admissions:
Intent e = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Admissions.class);
startActivity(e);
return true;

case R.id.contact:
Intent f = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Contact.class);
startActivity(f);
return true;

default:

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

Aactivity_map.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.university.Map" >

<fragment
   android:id="@+id/map"
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"/>    

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the Logcat when i click on the button in activity_contact.xml

```
07-26 02:22:16.012: I/Process(2244): Sending signal. PID: 2244 SIG: 9
07-26 02:22:20.062: D/dalvikvm(2268): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 86K, 7% free 2998K/3200K, paused 221ms, total 269ms
07-26 02:22:20.292: I/dalvikvm-heap(2268): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.783MB for 3932172-byte allocation
07-26 02:22:20.372: D/dalvikvm(2268): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 3% free 6835K/7044K, paused 79ms, total 79ms
07-26 02:22:21.552: D/gralloc_goldfish(2268): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-26 03:10:59.626: D/dalvikvm(2376): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 90K, 7% free 2997K/3204K, paused 191ms, total 202ms
07-26 03:10:59.876: I/dalvikvm-heap(2376): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.782MB for 3932172-byte allocation
07-26 03:11:00.126: D/dalvikvm(2376): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 6835K/7048K, paused 248ms, total 248ms
07-26 03:11:07.206: D/gralloc_goldfish(2376): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-26 03:11:09.626: D/dalvikvm(2376): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 57K, 3% free 7068K/7260K, paused 31ms, total 36ms
07-26 03:11:09.896: I/Choreographer(2376): Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-26 03:11:10.356: I/Choreographer(2376): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-26 03:11:21.527: D/dalvikvm(2376): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1266K, 17% free 7055K/8436K, paused 173ms, total 176ms
07-26 03:11:25.347: D/AndroidRuntime(2376): Shutting down VM
07-26 03:11:25.357: W/dalvikvm(2376): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0cefb20)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376): Process: com.example.university, PID: 2376
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.university/com.example.university.Map}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at com.example.university.Map.onCreate(Map.java:20)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     ... 11 more
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:597)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4778)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     ... 24 more
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.university-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.university-2, /system/lib]]
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:583)
07-26 03:11:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(2376):     ... 27 more
```

Comment: Are you compiling the Google Play Services library with your project?

Comment: there is an error "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment", please check if you have included this class in your project

Comment: @Charlesjean, I included this class in my project still Logcat appears! Where am I wrong?

Comment: Do you include the support Library, I think SupportMapFragment is in Support library V4.

Comment: @Charlesjean, In my Project->Properties->Android->com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment is not getting added as a library file. I guess Here is where i am getting stuck? Help me!

Comment: @Web you can refer to [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) to setup support library, and you also need to read http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html, spent less than two hours to read these, and you will totally get the point.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a few things wrong as you probably didn't follow all the steps in using Google Maps on your application:

1. Google Maps API key is supposed to be inside of the application tags in your manifest.
2. You are missing the play services meta tag (also inside the application tags):

   ```
   <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
   ```

Also make sure that you are compiling the play services with your project. If you're using Android-Studio, then the bottom of your `build.gradle` file should look like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
}
```

Comment: You mean I have to replace this with the code you mentioned? <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDGPcb88FGrYilWxe41RbWog38pSgNfp5o" />

Comment: No, I mean move the API key and the other meta tag I supplied to the inside of application tags: `<application>here</application>`

Comment: @Web same error? Try changing fragment's name field to `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"`